# removing characters (Newbie)

Tags: python

Im a newbie to python programming. How do you remove all characters in a text except the alphabet? or remove certain characters from the text. For example I want this text.

```
"#$@^@#$GD@%#DFQ#$%#$"
```

to print out as:

```
"GDDFQ"
```

I've tried googling, and all the answers are so complicated! Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @Bhargav not the exact duplicate..

Comment: `re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', '', s)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I guess you know a better duplicate. I have reopened

Comment: @BhargavRao How is this?... :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Better. Thanks :-)